# Cycle through form elements and check if they are required

Tags: php, html, forms

I would like to cycle through all the elements in a submitted form, assign each element its own variable, and then check if they are required. IF they are required, they will be checked if they are empty. So far, my form looks like this:

```
<form id="newitem" action="addnew.php" method="POST">
        <label for="title">Title: </label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required="required" /><br />
        <label for="description">Description: </label>
        <textarea name="description" id="website" cols="40" rows="5" ></textarea><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="formsubmit" value="true" /><!-- Option to know we've sumbited the form -->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

I then have it validated using this:

```
if (isset($_POST['formsubmit'])) {
    // form has been submitted
    $errors = Array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $$key = $value;
        if (!$value) {
            array_push($errors, 'Please enter a value for ' . $key);
        }
    }
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        echo 'Form validated';
    } else {
        showErrors($errors);
    }
}
```

This currently checks if the elements have a value. However, I would like it to check if that field is required, using the HTML `required="required"`.
Also, although I feel I do understand how this works, I'm not sure I do. I think `$$key = $value` basically means create a variable with the value of `$key` and give it the value of `$value`. So, `$key` is the name of the element, whilst `$value` is its value. However, I really don't get the `foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {`. I know it cycles though all the `$_POST`'s, but don't really know any more than that.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: PHP doesn't know about the `required` attribute. It only receives the form input `name` and corresponding `value`.  You could hold the whole form HTML markup in a string and parse it out with a parsing library to get those attributes, but that seems needlessly complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If think you are looking for something like

```
$errors = Array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a value for ' . $key;
    }
}
```

Foreach loops over an associative array and gives you the key and value of every 'element' in the array. In this case it will give you the name of a field in  $key and the value of a field in $value.

See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php for more info.

However, if a field was not submitted at all (i.e. not send from the client to the back-end), the $_FORM would not contain that field *at all*. Thus, to check if some required fields are filled, you would need to have that list on the serverside as well..! The code would then be something like:

```
$errors = Array();
$requiredfields = Array("somefield" => "...", "secondfield" => "...");
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    unset($requiredfields[$key]); // The encountered field $key is present
    if (empty($value)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a value for ' . $key;
    }
}
// Loop over all the required fields that are not found
foreach($requiredfields as $key => $val) {
    $errors[] = 'Please enter a value for ' . $key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are making a little confusion here...the server only receive name and value of  the `<input>` fields. PHP automatically create associative arrays ($_POST and $_GET) based on the `<form>` method. So you can't know which field have the `required` attribute, unless you insert some business logic

```
if (isset($_POST['formsubmit'])) {
    // form has been submitted
    $errors = Array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $$key = $value;
        //check that title has a value
        if ($key === "title" && !$value) {
            array_push($errors, 'Please enter a value for ' . $key);
        }
    }
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        echo 'Form validated';
    } else {
        showErrors($errors);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The common way to do this is to implement dual validation: client-side and server-side. Client validation would use JS to validate fields on more basic level and because it can be fooled (or JS disabled) you also need to implement server-side validation.

Using jQuery is very easy to check if field are required. Willem Mulder pointed out some basic, but nevertheless, valid valid to check for empty values.